# clean() method in Django ModelForm to avoid duplicate entries creates another instance upon updating the data. And doesn't even save a new instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have a few models, two of which are as follows:

```
class Receivables(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    pattern = RegexValidator(r'(RT|rt|rT|Rt)\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}', 'Enter RT Number properly!')
    rt_number=models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[pattern])
    discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    approved_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    approval_date=models.DateField(default=None)
    proposed_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    done_fractions=models.IntegerField()
    base_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    expected_value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

class Discharge(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_discharge=models.DateField(default=None)
    mould_charges=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    ct_charges=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    discharge_updated=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The views to save the new instance and update the existing one respectively, are:

1.

```
def discharge_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_discharge=DischargeForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if fm_discharge.is_valid():
            discharge=fm_discharge.save()
            ipd=IpdReport.objects.create(patient=discharge.patient, package=Package.objects.filter(patient=discharge.patient).order_by('-id').first(), receivables=Receivables.objects.filter(patient=discharge.patient).order_by('-id').first(), discharge=discharge)
            if discharge is not None:
                OngoingReport.objects.filter(ipdreport__patient=discharge.patient).delete()
                package=Package.objects.filter(patient=discharge.patient).order_by('-id').first().patient_type.patient_type
                if discharge.discharge_updated==False and package!='CASH':
                    UnclaimedPendingCases.objects.create(ipdreport=ipd)
                elif discharge.discharge_updated==True and package!='CASH':
                    ClaimedPendingCases.objects.create(ipdreport=ipd)
            fm_discharge=DischargeForm(request=request)
        return render(request, 'account/discharge.html', {'form':fm_discharge})
    else:
        fm_discharge=DischargeForm(request=request)
        return render(request, 'account/discharge.html', {'form':fm_discharge})
```

2. 

```
def update_discharge_view(request, id):
    di1=Discharge.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm1=di1.discharge_updated
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(request.POST)
        di=Discharge.objects.get(pk=id)
        form=DischargeForm(request.POST, instance=di, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            discharge=form.save()
    else:
        di=Discharge.objects.get(pk=id)
        form=DischargeForm(instance=di, request=request)
    return render(request, 'account/update_discharge.html', {'form':form})
```

The ModelForm looks as below:

```
class DischargeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Discharge
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'date_of_discharge': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request=kwargs.pop('request')
        self.instance=kwargs.pop('instance')
        super(DischargeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        pt=self.request.POST.get('patient')
        if not self.instance:
            rec=Receivables.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt).order_by('-id').first()
            if Discharge.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt, date_of_discharge__gt=rec.approval_date).exists():
                raise ValidationError('The patient has already been discharged!')
```

I want the discharge to be saved only once, for each time the patient gets treatment. Though it can be updated. Earlier I had written it like:

```
class DischargeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Discharge
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'date_of_discharge': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        pt=self.cleaned_data['patient']
        rec=Receivables.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt).order_by('-id').first()
        if Discharge.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt, date_of_discharge__gt=rec.approval_date).exists():
            raise ValidationError('The patient has already been discharged!')
```

without passing the request kwargs to `fm_discharge=DischargeForm()` in **views.py**

and it worked fine for the new instances being created. But it threw the same `ValidationError` for the instance coming in for the update, because, obviously the `discharge` instance already exists in the database for the same patient. Then, when I added the **init** method and accessed request and instance to resolve this, two problems showed up:

1. It created a new instance of the data which was supposed to be just updated.
2. As the new entry does not have an instance already, the **init** threw a KeyError for instance.

What can I do here? How to handle different scenarios such as this in the ModelForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, don't pop `instance` in `__init__`, as doing so will cause the `super()` call to tell the `ModelForm` that it will be working on *creating* a new object. Essentially it would be like the instance wasn't passed to the form at all.

For the `clean` call, just add a flag that the validation should only run when *creating* an instance (and not when updating) using `self.instance.pk`, so:

```
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        if not self.instance.pk:
            pt=self.cleaned_data['patient']
            rec=Receivables.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt).order_by('-id').first()
            if Discharge.objects.filter(patient__pk=pt, date_of_discharge__gt=rec.approval_date).exists():
                raise ValidationError('The patient has already been discharged!')
```